# Why does pgfplots package cause tikz layer to disappear?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wish to include a pgf-generated line plot and a tikz-generated graphical model in the same document. However, the presence of the `pgfplots` package (needed for the `axis` environment) seems to turn one of the layers in the graphical model invisible, as in the following almost-minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{f}
\pgfsetlayers{main,f}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(1, 5)(2, 10)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) [draw, circle, minimum size=40pt] {$a$};
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{f}
            \node (plate) [draw, minimum size=60pt] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I want to be drawn is a simple line graph followed by a circular node inside of a rectangular plate. What ends up being drawn is a simple line graph followed by a circular node, without the rectangular plate. Basically, the `f` layer seems to disappear when `pgfplots` is imported. This occurs in both `LaTeX` and `XeTeX`.

It should be noted that the first `tikzpicture` environment makes this a non-minimal example. It can be removed, and the invisibility of the layer toggled simply by commenting or uncommenting the `\usepackage{pgfplots}` line. However, I retained it as it illustrates my use case.

How can I use both the `axis` environment from `pgfplots` and have a second layer in my graphical model? Ideas? Workarounds? Explanations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update: This was a bug. The currently [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) version 1.7 has fixed this issue.**

The following code works and gives the expected output.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfdeclarelayer{f}
\pgfsetlayers{main,f}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(1, 5)(2, 10)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) [draw, circle, minimum size=40pt] {$a$};
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{f}
            \node (plate) [draw, minimum size=60pt] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output update]

## Old Answer

[This is a bug.](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3565873&group_id=224188&atid=1060656)

The suggested code before `\usepackage{pgfplots}` kind of works.

```
\ifx\pgfplothandlerjumpmarkmid\undefined
  \def\pgfplothandlerjumpmarkmid{123}
\fi
```

There are still “Undefined control sequence” errors in the `axis` environment—which is not present in the bug reporter's code. (Those error message don't appear to have any repercussion on the output, though).

To get rid of them, too, I defined three other macros *before* loading `pgfplots`.

(The `\if`-clauses are only there to check if the macros *really* aren't defined. `{123}` is just any arbitrary thing that makes them defined, could be `{42}` or even `{}` instead.)

I suggest you use the recent pgfplots unstable version (second option in the newest comment on the bug tracker linked above)!

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifx\pgfplothandlerjumpmarkmid\undefined
  \def\pgfplothandlerjumpmarkmid{123}
\fi
\ifx\pgfplothandlerconstantlinetomarkmid\undefined
  \def\pgfplothandlerconstantlinetomarkmid{123}
\fi
\makeatletter
\ifx\pgf@remember@layerlist@globally\undefined
  \def\pgf@remember@layerlist@globally{123}
\fi
\ifx\pgf@restore@layerlist@from@global\undefined
  \def\pgf@restore@layerlist@from@global{123}
\fi
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfdeclarelayer{f}
\pgfsetlayers{main,f}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(1, 5)(2, 10)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) [draw, circle, minimum size=40pt] {$a$};
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{f}
            \node (plate) [draw, minimum size=60pt] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and instantly helpful answer! Your code works for me :-)

Comment: @user17219 I'm glad I could help. Just remember that you probably can remove those lines when `pgfplots` gets updated.

Comment: Fixed in pgfplots 1.7

Comment: I can confirm that this is fixed in 1.7. Hooray!