# Is pgf-umlsd incompatible with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following document renders a nice sequence diagram for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}


% Sequence diagrams:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows} % for pgf-umlsd
\usepackage[underline=true,rounded corners=false]{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread{a}{Client}
\newthread{b}{Server}
\mess{a}{X}{b}
\mess{a}{Y}{b}
\begin{call}{a}{$Z_a$}{b}{$Z_b$}\end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

[image: Good sequence diagram]

But when I uncomment the line `\usepackage{pgfplots}`, the vertical lines and bars vanish:

[image: Bad sequence diagram]

In my *real* document I need the `pgfplots` package. So how can I make the two compatible?

---

<sup>I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXworks 0.4.4 r1003 on Windows XP SP2; pgf-umlsd 0.5 and pgfplots 1.6.1. I will also need it to work on an FC11 Linux system that's stuck at TeXLive 2007.</sup>

---

### Update

Although I can't find an *exact match* in the `pgf-umlsd` issues list, [issue 15](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/issues/detail?id=15&can=1) seems to describe the same conflict between `pgf-umlsd` and `pgf-umlcd`, and this was fixed in `pgf-umlsd` 0.7.

I locally updated the package to 0.7 in my Windows environment, but the problem persisted.

Comment: Both (with or without `pgflots`) yield identical results for me using TeXLive 2012. So, most  likely you are using older packages.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I managed to find some version numbers and edited them into the question. If versioning is an issue then that's a concern, as I'll also need this to work on an FC11 Linux system that's stuck at TeXLive 2007.

Comment: I guess you could try updating just the packages manually.

Comment: Why not install TeXLive 2012 on the linux system? If you don't have root access, you can install it somewhere in your home directory.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've updated pgf-umlsd to 0.7 but it has had no effect. I verified with `\listfiles` that the update took.

Comment: @IanThompson: I have root access, but FC11 has no TeXLive package > 2007 and I don't want to go down the potential dependency hell of a manual install at this stage. Plus this still has to work on Windows too.

Comment: You don't need to install via a package manager. Just use [this](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). It is very easy.

Comment: @IanThompson: I know I don't _need_ to, but it's a shared company server and I don't want to go down the manual install route. There must be a way to fix this with the versions I'm on, especially now that I have updated pgf-umlsd to the latest, and since pgfplots 1.6.1 was only released this past August. I'll try a manual update to pgfplots 1.7, though.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Could you possibly tell me what the package versions are for you?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yep I don't mind updating the _packages_ manually. It's the surrounding TeX environment that I'm not going to touch for this one feature.

Comment: My package versions are  `pgf-umlsd.sty 2009/09/30 v0.5`, and `pgfplots.sty 2012/10/26 v1.7`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thanks. Turns out v1.7 of pgfplots makes all the difference. Clearly you have a disciplined upgrade routine!

Comment: Hmmm... I wish. More like I am waiting for an updated version of a package to show up: [Incompatibility between currfile and enumitem?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79379/incompatability-between-currfile-and-enumitem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I can't find an *exact match* in the `pgf-umlsd` issues list, [issue 15](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/issues/detail?id=15&can=1) seems to describe the same conflict between `pgf-umlsd` and `pgf-umlcd`, and this was fixed in `pgf-umlsd` 0.7. However, updating `pgf-umlsd` to 0.7 did not solve the problem. I reverted it back to 0.5.

**Updating `pgfplots` to 1.7 *did* solve the problem** (due to a bug in 1.6.1 that the package author points out in the comments below).

Having done this, a cursory check shows that my usage of `pgfplots` doesn't appear to be broken anywhere in my real `.tex` files.

I had to perform this package update manually, but it works in both the Windows and FC11 Linux environments.

Comment: The reason is: pgfplots 1.6.1 introduced a bug which lead to broken layers (i.e. your question is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77594/why-does-pgfplots-package-cause-tikz-layer-to-disappear ). pgfplots 1.7 repairs this. Sorry.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Aha! Then, thanks not only for fixing it but also for allowing me to stop researching the reason this failed. :)